# TransactionInterceptor doesn't intercept @Transactional method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I made `@Transactional` method in `@Service` class.
Then, `TransactionInterceptor` doesn't intercept `@Transaction` method.
But when I make `@Transactional` method in `@Controller` class for test, then `TransactionInterceptor` intercept this method.
I want `TransactionInterceptor` intercept `@Transactional` method of `@Service` class.
How should I do?

Following code is my `Service class`. This code is be invoked by `@Controller` class.

```java
@Service
public class TokenProvider implements InitializingBean {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    private static final String AUTHORITIES_KEY = "auth"; // JWT Claim Key

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret; // private secret key
    @Value("${jwt.token-validity-in-seconds}")
    private long tokenValidityInMilliseconds; 
    private Key key;

    private final RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public TokenProvider(
            UserRepository userRepository,
            RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
    }

    //...

    @Transactional
    protected HttpHeaders _updateRefreshTokenAndGetHeader(String refreshToken, String accessToken, String newAccessToken) throws Exception {
        RefreshToken token = refreshTokenRepository.findByRefreshTokenAndAccessToken(refreshToken, accessToken)
                .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
        if (!token.isValid()) {
            throw new Exception("token is not valid.");
        }
        String name = TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName(); //null
        boolean transactional = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(); //false

        String updatedToken = updateRefreshToken(token, newAccessToken);
        return getHeaderForRefreshToken(updatedToken);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have in your configuration and code. Making your controllers transactional is a bad idea.

Comment: Remove the `InitializingBean` and annotate the `afterPropertiesSet` method with `@PostConstruct` instead. This way you will have a class proxy and it will work. Or make your method `public` to make it work. Finally if this is a service it shouldn't depend on HTTP types, that part should be in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem description as method visibility point to that issue/note:

> (i)Note: *Method visibility and @Transactional*
>
> When you use transactional proxies with Spring’s standard configuration, you should apply the @Transactional annotation **only to methods with public visibility**. If you do annotate protected, private, or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation, *no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the configured transactional settings*. If you need to annotate non-public methods, consider the tip in the following paragraph for class-based proxies or consider using AspectJ compile-time or load-time weaving (described later).

From: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations